# How to query for maximum field value in Lucene.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

We want to be able to return a single document with a maximum value for a particular field. A typical example would be,

```
max(date_time_field:*)
```

which returns the latest document in the index.

Is there any support for something like this in Lucene.Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are querying your index, but you can certainly order by the field in question, and then simply take the top document:

```
var sortBy = new Sort(new SortField("date_time_field", SortField.DOUBLE, true));
var hits = ... IndexSearcher.Search(query, null, 1, sortBy));

...

var doc = searcher.IndexSearcher.Doc(hits.ScoreDocs[0]);
```

Comment: I was looking for more of an aggregate function that returned a single document, rather than returning a sorted bulk and taking the top one... is that possible?

Comment: I don't think you can query for aggregates in Lucene